# Cannot convert String into Integer

Tags: java

```
String TypedMaxNumber = MaxValue.getText();
int Max = Integer.parseInt(TypedMaxNumber);
```

I am trying to do this, and I typed 1 in the text field I am getting an error.

Comment: `For input string: "" ` Check your input string. An empty string is probably not what you expect?

Comment: `MaxValue.getText()` returned an empty String. Why this is so, we cannot tell you without knowing more about `MaxValue`.

Comment: MaxValue is the Variable name of JTextField @Ray

Comment: need to see the code where MaxValue is defined

Comment: It seems to me that `MaxValue` is not referring to what you think it's referring to. Without seeing more of the code, that's hard to tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to check the String `TypedMaxNumber` before use it like this:

```
  if(TypedMaxNumber!=null && !TypedMaxNumber.equals(""))
      int Max = Integer.parseInt(TypedMaxNumber);
```

Comment: A null check is unnecessary, at least in that order. If it is null it will throw NPE at the `equals` method.

Comment: Now the order is right

Comment: Thanks it solve the confusion ..

Answer (score 0):

The method `parseInt` in `Integer` class throws `NumberFormatException`. Here is the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

You will have to add exception handling to make sure your code handles input strings which are not integers.

Please try below code:

```
String TypedMaxNumber = MaxValue.getText();
int Max = 0; // Assuming 0 is default if input string cannot be parsed to int
if (TypedMaxNumber != null && TypedMaxNumber.trim().length() > 0)
{
   try
   {
      Max = Integer.parseInt(TypedMaxNumber);
   }
   catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
   {
      // set to default value (here it is assumed as 0) if the string cannot be parsed to int.
      Max = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: He doesnt want to know how to handle the exception but wants to know why is it throwing it even if the passed value is 1

Answer (score 0):

you can even write it to preform a task if it's NaN

```
String TypedMaxNumber = MaxValue.getText();
int Max;
try {
    Max = Integer.parseInt(TypedMaxNumber);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("TypedMaxNumber is not a number");
}
```